# Icon Placeholder with FontAwesome5 and Bootstrap4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, font-awesome, placeholder, font-awesome-5

Does anyone know how to use a FontAwesome5 icon as a placeholder in a Bootstrap4 input? I've seen several solutions for previous versions, but none seem to work with the latest versions. Here's what I've got so far:

```
<input
  type="text"
  className="form-control"
  placeholder="&#xf002; Search"
  style={{
    fontFamily: 'FontAwesome, "Open Sans", Verdana, sans-serif',
    fontStyle: 'normal',
    fontWeight: 'normal',
    textDecoration: 'inherit'
  }}
/>
```

Comment: I've checked the [10 promoted websites that uses FontAwesome5](https://fontawesome.com/#used-on) and it looks like using icons in input placeholders has never been done before. It's a shame, I wanted to help you but my googling skills are not enough. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You can't add an icon and text.
You can try this one.

```
<input
  type="text"
  class="form-control"
  placeholder="&#xf002;"
  style="
     fontFamily:FontAwesome;
     fontStyle: normal;
     fontWeight: normal;
     textDecoration: inherit;
  "
/>
```

Comment: You can check my new answer.

Answer (score 0):

```css
input{
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: inherit;
}
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <input type="text" placeholder="&#xF002;"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input class="mainLoginInput" type="text" placeholder="&#61442;"/> <br/>
```

you should write code of icon in placeholder